# Sentence editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings

I wrote a simple sentence editor which capitalises first word, deletes redundant spaces and adds a dot in the end unless another sign of punctuation is already present. 
Please help me to improve my code, maybe by using some libraries.

```py
def correct_sentence(text: str) -> str:
    """
      returns a corrected sentence which starts with a capital letter
      and ends with a dot if needed. Also deletes redundant spaces.
    """
    marks = ['!', '?']
    text = text.strip()
    # checking if the last symbol is any of marks
    for i in range(len(marks)):
        if text[-1] != '.':
            if text[-1] == marks[i]:
                break
            else:
                text += '.'
    text_l = text.split()
    # deleting redundant spaces
    for word in text_l:
        if word == ',':
            indw = text_l.index(word)
            text_l[indw - 1] += word
            text_l.remove(word)
    text_l[0] = text_l[0].title()
    text = ' '.join(text_l)
    return text
```

---

As an example of how the code should work, the sentence:

```
"Hello   ,  my name is test"
```

Would be corrected to:

```
"Hello, my name is test."
```

Comment: It might help your question if you add a small example how this code is supposed to be used, which basically means an example sentence and the expected output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks good, has a docstring explaining precisely what is intended and typing annotations.

This is great and it also makes the review much more pleasant.

**Tests**

Before reviewing anything, I quite like adding a few test cases to see how the code behave and have a quick feedback loop if I try to change things in the code.

Here, based purely on the docstring, I wrote:

```
assert correct_sentence("a") == "A."
assert correct_sentence("abc") == "Abc."
assert correct_sentence("abc...") == "Abc..."
assert correct_sentence("abc .  .   .") == "Abc . . ."
assert correct_sentence(" abc  de f  ") == "Abc de f."
assert correct_sentence("aBcDe FgHiJk") == "Abcde FgHiJk." # Expected ?
correct_sentence("") # What should we do ?
```

Everything looks good to me except for the last 2 cases which you may want to look at.

**More tests**

The list above is not comprehensive and should be enhanced as we go through the review/add features. While going through the code, I realised that '?' should be considered as a proper sentence end. I wrote the following test cases which do not really convince me that things are working fine.

```
assert correct_sentence("a?") == "A?."
assert correct_sentence("abc.?.") == "Abc.?."
assert correct_sentence("abc..?") == "Abc..?."
```

Disclaimer: the following part of the review is based on the assumption that the current behavior is the one you want. It may not be the case but I hope the lessons provided will be interesting anyway.

**Look like a native**

I highly recommend [Ned Batchelder's talk called "Loop Like A Native"](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html). The main point is that whenever we are using "range(len(iterable))" there is usually a better (more pythonic, more concise, more efficient, clearer).

Here:

```
# checking if the last symbol is any of marks
for i in range(len(marks)):
    if text[-1] != '.':
        if text[-1] == marks[i]:
            break
        else:
            text += '.'
```

can be rewritten:

```
# checking if the last symbol is any of marks
for mark in marks:
    if text[-1] != '.':
        if text[-1] == mark:
            break
        else:
            text += '.'
```

**Stopping early**

When `text[-1] == '.'`, the loop above will have no effect. Thus, we could `break` as soon as we do `text += '.'`.

We get

```
        if text[-1] == mark:
            break
        else:
            text += '.'
            break
```

which can be rewritten:

```
        if text[-1] != mark:
            text += '.'
        break
```

**Reorganise the logic**

Now it is clearer that `text[-1]` will stay unchanged during the whole loop as we exit the loop as soon as we do something that would change the value.

We can use a variable for this, we can move the check `if text[-1] != '.'` before the loop.

We get something like:

```
last = text[-1]
if last != '.':
    for mark in marks:
        if last != mark:
            text += '.'
        break
```

Now, it is obvious that only the first elements from `marks` will ever be considered (we break at the end of the first iteration) and this explains the surprising behavior described above.

**Loop with the `,`**

The second loop is commented `# deleting redundant spaces` but we could literally remove it and still have the redundant spaces removed. The comment needs to be adjusted to the relevant part.

It looks like what you are trying to achieve is removing space before comma.

I've added the following test cases:

```
assert correct_sentence("a,b,c,d") == "A,B,C,D."
assert correct_sentence("a, b ,c , d") == "A, b ,c, d."
assert correct_sentence("a, b ,c , d , , , ,e") == "A, b ,c, d,, , ,e."
```

Question: should we do this only when `word == ","` or should when `word` starts wich `","` ?

Let's see what we can try to improve.

1. You are trying to update the list as you iterate through it. This makes everything quite fragile.
2. You are calling `word` to know the position of the word you are considering. This could be provided by `enumerate`.

There are many things that are still to be improved but I think there are many defects you should try to fix first before going any further.

At this stage, the code looks like:

```
def correct_sentence(text: str) -> str:
    """
      returns a corrected sentence which starts with a capital letter
      and ends with a dot if needed. Also deletes redundant spaces.
    """
    text = text.strip()
    if not text:
        return ''

    # checking if the last symbol is any of marks
    marks = ['!', '?']
    last = text[-1]
    if last != '.':
        for mark in marks:
            if last != mark:
                text += '.'
            break

    text_l = text.split()
    for word in text_l:
        if word == ',':
            indw = text_l.index(word)
            text_l[indw - 1] += word
            text_l.remove(word)
    text_l[0] = text_l[0].title()
    # deleting redundant spaces with split & join
    return ' '.join(text_l)


assert correct_sentence("a") == "A."
assert correct_sentence("a?") == "A?."
assert correct_sentence("abc") == "Abc."
assert correct_sentence("abc...") == "Abc..."
assert correct_sentence("abc.?.") == "Abc.?."
assert correct_sentence("abc..?") == "Abc..?."
assert correct_sentence("abc .  .   .") == "Abc . . ."
assert correct_sentence(" abc  de f  ") == "Abc de f."
assert correct_sentence("aBcDe FgHiJk") == "Abcde FgHiJk." # Expected ?
assert correct_sentence("") == '' # What should we do ?
assert correct_sentence("a,b,c,d") == "A,B,C,D."
assert correct_sentence("a, b ,c , d") == "A, b ,c, d."
assert correct_sentence("a, b ,c , d , , , ,e") == "A, b ,c, d,, , ,e."
```

**Organisation**

If you want to make you life easier, you may want to split your function into smaller functions with a single responsability. This will also make testing easier.

Comment: For checking last symbol, does that work?  that break will leave the for straight away.  Can't that entire chunk be done more succinctly as `if not text.endswith(('.', '?', '!')):` `text += '.'` ?

Comment: @Baldrickk As far as I can tell, that behavior was already in OP's code. I tried to hilight that issue and explain it but I'd rather leave it to them to fix it. Also AlexV's great answer provides a proper way to handle this.

Comment: Yeah, I read your answer, commented, refined, and only then read Alex's answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my oppinion, your code looks quite good. You have a consistent [style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), appropriate [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), and a well-structured function with clear code.

Nevertheless, I would like to point out a few points that can make your code more *Pythonic*.

The way you check for the final mark can be improved and made more concise. Instead of checking all the elements of `marks` by hand, you can use [`str.endswith(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) with multiple *suffixes* like so:

```
marks = ('!', '?', '.')
if not text.endswith(marks):
    text += '.'
```

**Note:** `marks` is now a tuple and not a list anymore.

Handling those `,`'s kept me thinking longer than I would like to admit. I thought I would be easy to also handle cases like `, ,  ,` or `,,`, but as always, nothing is quite as easy as it seems. It's always a bit tricky to index and/or iterate lists that gets modified in the meantime. One approach is to use another list to store the results, another very common approach is to index the list from the back. I chose the later one and came up with the following solution:

```
# avoid whitespace in front of , as well as multiple ,
for i in reversed(range(len(text_l))):
    word = text_l[i]
    if re.fullmatch(r',+', word):
        if not text_l[i-1].endswith(',') and i > 0:
            text_l[i-1] += ','
        del text_l[i]
```

I chose to work with Python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)gex module to take care of repeated `,` characters. `text_l[i-1].endswith(',')` was added to make sure that a word does not get more than one `,` and `i > 0` was added to handle the edge case of a leading `,`, which would otherwise wrap around.

The capitalization might also need a slight retouch, since `str.title()` has some quirks which are listed in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title). This can be seen in a simple example: `print("They're".title())` prints `They'Re`, which is probably not what you are looking for. A quick-and-dirty fix a came up with was to use `text_l[0] = text_l[0][0].upper()+text_l[0][1:]` to capitalize only the first letter. This even works for single letter words like `i`:

```
test = "i"
print(test.upper()+test[1:])
>>> I
```

With all these changes the code now looks as follows:

```
def correct_sentence(text: str) -> str:
    """
    returns a corrected sentence which starts with a capital letter
    and ends with a dot if needed. Also deletes redundant spaces.
    """
    text = text.strip()

    # checking if the last symbol is any of marks
    marks = ('!', '?', '.')
    if not text.endswith(marks):
        text += '.'

    text_l = text.split()
    # avoid whitespace in front of , as well as multiple ,
    for i in reversed(range(len(text_l))):
        word = text_l[i]
        if re.fullmatch(r',+', word):
            if not text_l[i-1].endswith(',') and i > 0:
                text_l[i-1] += ','
            del text_l[i]

    # capitalize first letter only, since .title() has some quirks.
    text_l[0] = text_l[0][0].upper()+text_l[0][1:]

    return ' '.join(text_l)
```

I also took the liberty to change the comment to describe what you actually want to do.